# Non-execution of VOLATILE functions and INSERTS within Postgresql RULE

Tags: postgresql, immutability, rules

I am running into a wierd issue with the execution (or non-execution) of certain queries within postgresql RULES. This is a companion (but different) question to [Postgresql subquery execution within ON UPDATE rule (maybe bug in postgresql?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721788/postgresql-subquery-execution-within-on-update-rule-maybe-bug-in-postgresql) - but as it turns out, there is a related issue of certain queries not executing at all within postgresql RULEs, versus just the issue of query execution order.

Consider the following code block:

```
DROP TABLE foo_table;
DROP TABLE bar_table;

--------------

CREATE TABLE foo_table (c1 text, c2 int);
CREATE TABLE bar_table (c1 text, c2 int);

--------------

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION debug_immutable(anyelement) RETURNS integer AS $$

pg_raise('notice', 'debug(): ' . json_encode($args[0]));

return rand(1, 10000);

$$ LANGUAGE PLPHP IMMUTABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION debug_volatile(anyelement) RETURNS integer AS $$

pg_raise('notice', 'debug(): ' . json_encode($args[0]));

return rand(1, 10000);

$$ LANGUAGE PLPHP VOLATILE;

-------------

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE foo_update_rule AS ON UPDATE TO foo_table DO INSTEAD
(

SELECT debug_immutable('debug_immutable call 1'::text); -- Query #1

SELECT debug_volatile('debug_volatile call 1'::text);   -- Query #2

INSERT INTO foo_table (c1, c2) values ('foo', 123456);  -- Query #3

INSERT INTO bar_table (c1, c2) values ('bar', 123456);  -- Query #4

SELECT debug_immutable('debug_immutable call 2'::text); -- Query #5

SELECT debug_volatile('debug_volatile call 2'::text);   -- Query #6
);

-----------------------------------------------

UPDATE foo_table SET c1 = NULL where c1 = 'aaa';

SELECT * FROM foo_table;

SELECT * FROM bar_table;
```

The output only displays the following:

```
NOTICE:  plphp: debug(): "debug_immutable call 1"
NOTICE:  plphp: debug(): "debug_immutable call 2"
Total query runtime: 46 ms.
0 rows retrieved.
```

And both foo_table and bar_table shows to be empty after the code block is executed:

```
# select * from foo_table;
 c1 | c2 
----+----
(0 rows)

# select * from bar_table;
 c1 | c2 
----+----
(0 rows)
```

The output implies that only queries #1 and #5 are executed, and queries #2, 3, 4 and 6 are never executed. Why is this? How can the above code block be changed so that queries #2, 3, 4 and 6 are executed?

Comment: Point is that you abuse (and seem to misunderstand) the rule system. What you want to investigate can be accomplished by just investigating the resulting query plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immutable functions are evaluated at the planning stage, before the query is executed. The volatile ones are evaluated on a per need basis. You've zero rows returned, so they're never called.

Comment: Ack you are right!! I added the following (INSERT INTO foo_table (c1) VALUES('aaa');)to insert a row into foo_table before the update and now all 6 queries are executed! Thanks!